# persisting memory in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Here is my code, I pass the auth state and token through props to other components:
The problem is that when I refresh the page, it redirects me to the homepage.

Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            account: {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            },
           
            token: "",
            auth: false
        };

    }
    
    
    confirm = async (email) => {
            let result;
            let stateAccount;
            let authToken;
            let myCookie;
            let storedCookie;

            try {
                result = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/abc/dosomething`, {email},{withCredentials: true});

                stateAccount = this.state.account
                stateAccount.email = email;
                this.setState({stateAccount});


                console.log(result);

                if (this.state.account.email === result.data.Email && this.state.account.password === result.data.OTPCode) {
                    authToken = result.headers.accesstoken;
                    this.setState({token: authToken});

                    myCookie = this.addCookies();
                    myCookie = myCookie.split('=');
                    storedCookie = myCookie[1].trim();

                } else {
                    console.log(`Invalid Login!`);
                    
                }


                let history = this.props.history;



                if(this.state.token === storedCookie){
                    console.log("Successful Login!");
                    console.log(`found cookie: ${storedCookie}`);
                    this.setState({auth: true});
                    history.push({pathname: "/some-endpoint/abc", state: {stateAccount}});

                }else{
                    this.setState({errorMessage: "Invalid Login!"});
                }



            }catch(error){ //set this to Permission Denied in production
                console.log(`${error.data}`});
            }
        }
    
    notLoggedInhomePage = () =>{

        if(!this.state.auth) {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.account.email} onChange={this.handleChange} name="email"/>
                    
                        <label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <input type="password" value={this.state.account.password} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter One Time Password" name="password"/>
                    

                    <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.someFunction(String(this.state.account.email))}>Do Something</button>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.someOtherFunction()}>Do something else</button>
                </form>
            );
        }else{
            return(<Redirect to="/logged-in-page/signed-in" />);
        }
}


      render(){

        return(
            <Router>
                {this.notLoggedInhomePage()}
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/list" exact component={AComponent} auth={this.state.auth} account={this.state.account} token={this.state.token}  />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

I know that state is an temporary-memory, but what I am looking to do is, when I refresh the page, I want the user to stay on the same page that they were on before refreshing. However what happens is that they get redirected back to the home page (which is the login screen), because the this.state.auth will be equal to false as seen above in the notLoggedInhomePage.

What is the best solution to fix the above problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **You could make use of [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

- Set your state to `app_state` storage when your token is changed.
- Check if `app_state` exist on the mount or using a fresh state.

**Something like this:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = localStorage.getItem("app_state") ?? {
      account: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
      },
      token: "",
      auth: false
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.token !== prevState.token) { // Set a new state if token change
      localStorage.setItem("app_state", this.state);
    }
  }
...the rest of your component
```

Comment: Yeah. It depends on your babel settings. But thay are similar in this case. Glad it helps

Answer (score -1):

Information that needs to persist can be put into browser storage, and that includes an `authToken`. You can choose from 2 flavors of browser storage:

- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) -> accessible across all tabs and windows that use the same domain; survives even when all such tabs are closed, and available again if a new tab is opened later for the same domain.
- [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) -> accessible only to the tab that sets it; gone as soon as that tab is closed.

Set a value: `localStorage.token = authToken;`
Get a value: `authToken = localStorage.token;`
Remove value: `localStorage.removeItem("token");`

Note that **only strings** can be stored and retrieved. If you attempt to store anything other than a string, it will do `.toString()` on it first. That is why in general it is best to use `JSON.stringify(obj)` when setting a value, and `JSON.parse(valueFromStorage)` when getting a value.

A final note, there is no need to copy tokens from storage into React state. In fact doing so may work against you because every API call you make will (or should) produce a new fresh token, that you should put in storage again. The last thing you want is old tokens being cached in long-lived components, because they will stop being valid after their lifetime expires.